# Animations make my app crash: How can I remove them?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-animation

In my app, I create view controller objects as I need them. When a view controller goes away, I get rid of it by calling -removeFromSuperview on it's view and then set the retaining property to nil.

That way my app uses very low memory all the time. But there's a problem: I have heavy animations going on in some view controllers, and every animation always has an animation delegate which is self. Now the thing that happens is: When there are animations running and I drop the view controller, it goes away - and at some point when one of those animations finishes it seems to crash.

So the question is: How to remove any running animation from a view and all it's subviews?

Comment: I think you're asking the wrong question.  If the application crashes on the completion of the animations, you should find out why it is crashing, not just how to remove the animations.  It sounds like there's something wrong at a lower level here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed. There may be some confusion on how you add/remove the subview, and how you retain/release it. Make sure that you are following these guidelines:

```
// To add
AView * aSubView = [[AView alloc] init];
[aContainerView addSubview:aSubView];
[aSubView release]; // aSubView is retained by aContainerView
```

... and later on

```
// To remove
[aSubView removeFromSuperview]; // and nothing else!
```

Do **not** do this:

```
[self removeFromSuperview]; // Don't cut the branch on which you are sitting
```

(you already knew that!)